# Docker/Traefik behind a proxy

Tags: networking, firefox, docker

- In my docker-compose file (on Ubuntu 18.04) I have the following configuration;
- The Apache part

  - *PROJECT_BASE_URL* is defined *drupal.docker.localhost*_

```yaml
    labels:
    - "traefik.http.routers.${PROJECT_NAME}_apache.rule=Host(`${PROJECT_BASE_URL}`)"
    - "traefik.http.services.${PROJECT_NAME}_apache.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
```

- The Traefik configuration part:

```yaml
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.0
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_traefik"
    command: --api.insecure=true --providers.docker -log.level=DEBUG
    ports:
    - '8080:80'
#    - '8080:8080' # Dashboard
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

- when I tried to access *http://drupal.docker.localhost:8080/*

  - in the docker/Traefik logs I see that Traefik redirects to the right IP address with the right port (in my case http://172.21.0.8:80)
- but Firefox answers me that the corporate DNS could not resolve the name.

  - If I access directly *http://172.21.0.8:80* I access to my local Website!
- Why does the Firefox needs to access the Corporate DNS ?

#### additional information

- Answer of Firefox:

```
État 503 Service Unavailable VersionHTTP/1.1 Transfert1,21 Ko (taille 885 o) Priorité de la requêteHighest Response Headers Content-Length 885 Content-Type text/html;charset=utf-8 Date Mon, 24 Jul 2023 11:12:06 GMT Mime-Version 1.0 Server squid/3.5.27 Via 1.1 prxpusx104 (squid/3.5.27), 1.1 prxpusx006 (squid/3.5.27) X-Cache MISS from prxpusx104 X-Cache MISS from prxpusx006 X-Squid-Error ERR_DNS_FAIL 0
```

#### Firefox proxy configuration

- Firefox seems correctly configured
- if I access *http://drupal.docker.localhost/* I get the response of the Apache on the Host (on my PC):

```bash
jpmena@jpmena-ThinkCentre-M710t:/var/log/apache2$ tail -f access.log
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jul/2023:14:31:44 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3477 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/113.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jul/2023:14:31:44 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 502 "http://drupal.docker.localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/113.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jul/2023:14:31:44 +0200] "GET /icons/ubuntu-logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3624 "http://drupal.docker.localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/113.0"
```

- but if I access the same URL but with the port of Traefik (*http://drupal.docker.localhost:8080*), Firefox asks the proxy to solve the domain name

  - The Tarefik logs confirm that it has correctly redirected to *http://172.21.0.8:80*
  - If I access *http://172.21.0.8:80* from my PC I get access to my Drupal website
- NB: this Traefik works perfectly on my home PC which is not behind a proxy

Comment: Why even have Traefik if it’s not doing anything sensible? // Unless you provide the exact and full error message that Firefox shows, guessing is the best we can do.

Comment: État
503
Answer of Firefox:
Service Unavailable
VersionHTTP/1.1
Transfert1,21 Ko (taille 885 o)
Priorité de la requêteHighest

Response Headers
_Content-Length
 885
Content-Type
 text/html;charset=utf-8
Date
 Mon, 24 Jul 2023 11:12:06 GMT
Mime-Version
 1.0
Server
 squid/3.5.27
Via
 1.1 prxpusx104 (squid/3.5.27), 1.1 prxpusx006 (squid/3.5.27)
X-Cache
 MISS from prxpusx104
X-Cache
 MISS from prxpusx006
X-Squid-Error
 ERR_DNS_FAIL 0_

Comment: Please [add this to your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1799222/edit), which you can edit at any time. // So from what I gather is that your _browser_ has a proxy set. Do you have appropriate proxy exceptions set so that `drupal.docker.localhost` is _not_ directed to the proxy? Is this even something you can change or is it locked down by software policies?

Comment: I completed my question

Comment: If Firefox were “correctly configured” for your use case, it would not send the request to the proxy. At this stage my only conclusion can be: No, you do not have appropriate proxy exceptions set. Your problem isn’t with Docker or DNS or even the proxy. It is only with Firefox and its proxy settings. // So, more specifically: What is the proxy configuration? Please provide the values of all fields from the proxy config dialog.